# Chained Payments and PayPal

Tags: paypal

I'v question regarding PayPal chained payments. I employ freelancers (who are the secondary receivers) from different countries who provide online services to my customers. The customer should pay directly to the freelancers and also directly to me (my share). I think that chained payments are the best option because in this case the freelancer can't see the customer details and vice verse. One problem remain though, I understand that before the payment to the freelancer is done, it pass through my account. If this is the case, then the whole sum that the client paid would pass through my account and for tax reasons the whole sum is considered as my income while in fact only part of it goes to me. I have no problem with the payment to the receivers pass through me, but I don't want it to be documented as income, only the part that goes to me should be documented as income  and  the share of the receivers should be documented from the beginning as their share. Is it possible with this option?

Comment: Do you mean, you want [Each Receiver Pays the Fee in a Chained Payment](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_APIntro#id091QF0N0MPF__id092SH0Y0E5Z)?

Comment: No.When I transfer the money to my company bank account.I then have to provide details to the IRS.They ask me to show every transaction that was done on the business account.So if client paid 100$, then for the IRS my taxed income is 100$. Say that the client bought in 100$ but 55$ went to the freelancers who provide the service:my income is 45$. But the IRS wants prove that the 55$ served as legitimate expense of the business.I want the payment to split directly between me and the freelancers or be written like this,with client only see that he paid the whole some to me.Is it possible?

Comment: You want it to appear to the client that payment is made to a single receiver, not multiple, but don't want to be taxed on the full payment as the primary receiver? Correct?

Comment: It won't matter if you receive the full amount to the IRS. As long as they can see you paid that out to the freelancer you won't be taxed on it. eg. You receive $100 (as the primary receiver), then paypal automatically pays $55 from your account to the freelancer (which is the secondary receiver in the chained payment). The IRS sees this as income of $100 and expenses of $55, giving a net taxable income of $45.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is Parallel payments, not chained payments.

**Parallel payments**
[image: Adaptive Parallel Payments]

**Chained payments**
[image: Adaptive Chained Payments]

Also take a look at [Introducing Adaptive Payments](https://cms.paypal.com/uk/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_APIntro)

Comment: Is it possible to implement Delayed Chained Payment with the Recurring Payment in Paypal? and if yes then how?

Comment: But in chained customer can see all the service provider. OP want to hide this too. So chained will be apt to him. But he also talks about payment should not documented as his income. Let me know your thoughts on this. Thanks @Robert

Answer (score 0):

no . acutally I would like the same, chained payment, not parallel as I don't want someone to know what's my share. just want to set up primary receiver the person who will do the stuff, and I , comissioner, am the receiver number 2